# Vue3 How to pass input's value to method in @change="func(param)"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an input field and I need to call the function every time when value is changed and pass the new value to the function. I couldn't find how to do it.

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
    <el-input
    type="text"
    :value="scope.row.name"
    v-model="queryName"
    @change="changeQueryName(scope.row.id, ???.queryName)">
    </el-input>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `$event`

```js
@change="changeQueryName($event, scope.row.id, ???.queryName)"
```

This is de doc [HTMLElement: Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

In the `changeQueryName()` function you can use `event.target.value`

```js
changeQueryName(event, id, queryName) {
   console.log(event.target.value)
}
```